# angularjs gmt-5 date filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a unix timestamp, 1382342400, which I want to adjust to the proper timezone.

In GMT, this is Mon, 21 Oct 2013 08:00:00 GMT

In GMT-5 (EST) this should be Mon, 21 Oct 2013 03:00:00 GMT

When I do `{{1382342400 * 1000 |date: 'h:mm'}}` I get 4:00 which appears to be GMT-4

If I do `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`, I correctly get 300, which is 5 hours in minutes which is what I am expecting.

With all of this said, how can I use the angular filter to represent gmt-5?

Comment: I just plugged that same binding (`{{1382342400 * 1000 | date: 'h:mm'}}`) into a test partial and it worked great.  I'm in GMT-6 and it said `2:00`.  And when I did `new Date(1382342400 * 1000);`, it printed out `Mon Oct 21 2013 02:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT)`, which is correct.

Comment: The date is always assumed to be in unix and then adjusted to your timezone.